# Network Manager re-installation in Linux Mint (KDE version)

Tags: networking, linux-mint, kde, networkmanager

I need some help to re-install the Network Manager.
I installed WICD to see if it was a better Network Manager than the regular one, but I didn't like it so I uninstalled it.
Now I have difficulty to reinstall the regular Network Manager in Linux Mint (KDE version).
I tried many different things. I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager

sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome network-manager
```

And many other things, but nothing worked.
Actually I think the Network Manager is perhaps running in the background because when I run:

```
nmcli dev
```

I get:
[image]

I don't see the Network Manager icon (which I think it's called applet) in System Tray. And strangely enough when I run:
nm-applet
A Network Manager icon (or applet) appears temporary in System Tray BUT that Network Manager is NOT the one I used to have before. So I don't quite understand what is going on...

Before installing WICD I removed the Network Manager, but I did not remove the config files, perhaps it can be of some help.

My system is:
Kernel: 4.4.0-53-generic x86_64 (64 bit) Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.8.7 Distro: Linux Mint 18.1 Serena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. If anyone faces the same issue do the following.

**Launch Synaptic Package Manager**, find your Network Manager package, right click on it, select `Mark for Reinstallation`, then select `Mark Recommended for Installation` and select whatever is needed (highlighted). For me it was `network-manager-gnome` and `plasma-nm`. Then "Apply".